# Acidic strength order of mineral acids in acetic acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

> Explain this acidic strength order $\ce{H2SO4} > \ce{HCl} > \ce{HNO3}$ in acetic acid.

#### My Attempt

Stability of conjugate base is proportional to the acidic strength of acids in acetic acid.

1. $\ce{SO4^2-}$ has two resonance structures.
2. $\ce{NO3-}$ has three resonance structures.
3. $\ce{Cl-}$ is stable due to octet formation.

As for electronegativity order, Cl is on par with N (almost equal).

According to stability, $\ce{HNO3}$ must me more acidic than $\ce{HCl}.$ Also, electronegativity of N & Cl is almost the same.

So, according to me, the order must be $\ce{HNO3} > \ce{H2SO4} > \ce{HCl}.$

Where am I wrong? Please explain.

Comment: The anions are so different that "comparing" them for a trend is meaningless.

Comment: The strength of the acid is not only dependent on the stability of the conjugate base but also on the proton-accepting ability of the solvent (For protic acids). HCl for example, is a strong acid in water and weak acid in pure acetic acid for this reason.

Comment: @MaxW but such questions are asked in exams.if there is no way to compare them then how should i approach such question in exams.

Comment: @ShoubhikRajMaiti i want to know more about "Effects of different solution on acid strength ". Can you please add me in a separate chat so that i can ask little bit more. please.

Comment: Note that you should consider rather $\ce{HSO4- } $ instead of $\ce{SO4^2-}$